# Проверка пользователя на регистрацию Telegram Bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Пишу Telegram бота используя библиотеку pyTelegramBotAPI, и хочу сделать проверку пользователя на регистрацию.

```
def info(message):
    registration = []
    message = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'blabla')

    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, registration)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['test'])
def registration(message, registration):
    if message.text == 'blabla':
        registration += 1
    elif registration == 1:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы зарегистрированы!')
    elif registration == 0:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы не зарегистрированы!')
```

При выполнении кода выводит эту ошибку

```
TypeError: check_registration() missing 1 required positional argument: 'registration'
```

Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Просто так сделай

```
def info(message):
    registration_list = []
    message = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'blabla')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, registration, registration_list)

def registration(message, registration_list):
```